# Boost Thread segmentation fault on join()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I have following piece of code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void foo() {
    puts("foo()");
}

int main() {
    boost::thread t(foo);
    //t.start_thread();
    puts("join()");
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine, but when I uncomment `start_thread()` call it crushes in `join()`.

**Why does the `start_thread()` call cause segmentation fault in `join()`?**

I use:

> g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
>
> Boost Version: 1.54.0.1ubuntu1

`g++ -std=c++11 -static main.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lpthread -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: SIGSEGV is just not one usually expects from such mature and widely used library.

Answer (score 2):

Boost thread gets executed in the constructor of `boost::thread`, there is no need and should not to start it explicitly. Actually, the ctor of `boost::thread` calls `start_thread()`, `start_thread()` calls `start_thread_noexcept()` which implements the creation of thread on different platforms,  it calls `pthread_create()` if you use `pthread`, you can check this from the source code of boost thread. I'm wondering why this function is public.
**Update**: just checked out the new version of boost(1.57), this function is declared as private now, in the file `boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp`:

```
private:
    bool start_thread_noexcept();
    bool start_thread_noexcept(const attributes& attr);
//public:
    void start_thread()
    {
      if (!start_thread_noexcept())
      {
        boost::throw_exception(thread_resource_error());
      }
    }
    void start_thread(const attributes& attr)
    {
      if (!start_thread_noexcept(attr))
      {
        boost::throw_exception(thread_resource_error());
      }
    }
```

so it will fail to compile if you want to call it.

Comment: I was also baffled by the public `start_thread()` function. When I saw that `start_thread()` was public, I assumed the API required you to call `start_thread()` --> resulting in my code exiting not nicely and then the debugger was having trouble showing me how it was failing. I finally noticed 2x the print outs which is what led me to reread the documentation and reimplement my code to not call `start_thread()`.

Comment: I have 1.54 boost so having `start_thread` as a `public` function has been around for a long time...